# Symfony - Making dev environment inaccessible in prod

Tags: php, symfony

I recently deployed a symfony project and noticed that the dev environment is still accessible.

The following URL loads the prod version of the project:

`http://domain.com/app.php/index`

The following URL loads the dev version of the project:

`http://domain.com/app_dev.php/index`

I was wondering if it is possible to make the dev version of the project inaccessible in the prod environment?

I appreciate any advice, thanks in advance!

Comment: Simplest way would be to delete `app_dev.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That sure is simple! However, when I navigate to app_dev.php now I get an internal server error, rather than a page not found error.

Comment: just remove `app_dev.php` and then clear the cache `$ php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`

Comment: Thanks @falsecrypt. Just cleared the cache, still getting internal server error when trying to navigate to the deleted `app_dev.php`.

Comment: Are you explicitly navigating to `app_dev.php`? Your site should be served in prod mode if you navigate to `http://domain.com/index` - I assume that you are using `mod_rewrite`... or maybe this is the problem? It certainly sounds you might have to dig into your web server logs and get more detail on that 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: You can delete `app_dev.php` then you need to physically remove `dev` folder in `app/cache` folder and you need to remove `dev_config.yml`, too. Another solution might be rewriting some rules in `.htaccess` file for `dev` mode

Comment: you don't have to remove `config_dev.yml`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines of code in your app_dev.php

```
 // this check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to        production servers.
 // feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
 if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
                                          '127.0.0.1',
                                           '::1',)))
 {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more    information.');
 }
```